# Sending file over socket - bind()

Tags: sockets, python-3.5

I'm trying to learn how to use sockets and have put together a class that takes in an ip, port and file to send. It works on localhost but not when I pass it the ip of another host on the network.

This is the traceback:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "script.py", line 91, in servr
    servr.bind((self.ip, self.port))
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 163, in <module>
    main()
  File "script.py", line 157, in main
    rmt.client()
  File "script.py", line 85, in client
    machines.update({self.ip: {self.port: path.get()}})
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

This is the code:

```
class Remote:

    def __init__(self, ip, port, filename):
        self.ip = socket.gethostbyname(ip)
        self.port = int(port)
        self.filename = filename

    def client(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=1)
        path = pool.apply_async(self.servr)
        time.sleep(1)
        client = socket.socket()
        client.connect((self.ip, self.port))
        with open(self.filename, 'rb') as file:
            data = file.read()
            client.sendall(data)
        machines = {}
        try:
            with open("machines.pickle", 'rb') as file:
                machines = pickle.load(file)
        except (EOFError, FileNotFoundError):
            pass
        finally:
            with open("machines.pickle", 'wb') as file:
                machines.update({self.ip: {self.port: path.get()}})
                pickle.dump(machines, file)

    def servr(self):
        servr = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        servr.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        servr.listen(5)
        client, addr = servr.accept()
        file = open("." + self.filename, 'wb') if platform.system() == 'Linux' else os.popen(
        "attrib +h " + self.filename, 'wb')
        data = client.recv(6000)
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
        file = "." + self.filename if platform.system() == 'Linux' else self.filename
        os.chmod(file, os.stat(file).st_mode | 0o111)
        client.close()
        servr.close()
        return os.path.abspath(file)
```

I tried binding to `("", 0)` but then the code doesn't run past the call to `accept()`. Maybe the port is already in use? I've also tried `socket.settimeout()`, and although it breaks out of `accept()`, the program runs until dict update on the first method but there was no file sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a server, `.bind(('',port))` is typical and means accept client connections on any interface.  Using port 0 is not typical...using a number >1024 is typical.  The code won't run past `accept` until a client connects to the server, so stopping at `accept` is normal as well.